# How to recursively traverse a Snowflake role grant hierarchy in Python?

Tags: python, sql, recursion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, directed-acyclic-graphs

Has anyone written Python code to traverse a Snowflake Role hierarchy?

A role can be granted a role which can be granted a role.

Nested roles are possible.

In Python, I want to start with a specific role

1. Query all grants to the role that are roles
2. store each of those in a unique list
3. for each of those roles execute a SQL statement that will query all roles granted to that role

and traverse down the hierarchy, not missing a single role and also not traversing a role that has already been queried or that is in the list to be queried

Something recursive to crawl this tree using Python would be helpful.

At this point, given a role, I have no way to execute a SQL statement that will give me all the first level sub-roles granted to the given role.

There is no way to select on fields and get the grant that are just of type ROLE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Once complete, I will post all contributions and the final the code to a github account.

thank you,

I am expecting to end up with a list of Snowflake roles with no duplicates in the list.

Answer (score 3):

You said "At this point, given a role, I have no way to execute a SQL statement that will give me all the first level sub-roles granted to the given role." - it is not true.

You can do it this way:

```
SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE THE_ROLE;  -- replace THE_ROLE with your role name
SELECT distinct "name" FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id())) where "privilege" = 'USAGE' and "granted_on" = 'ROLE';
```

Well, they are actually two queries.

But it can be achieved with one too:

```
select name
from snowflake.account_usage.grants_to_roles
where grantee_name = 'THE_ROLE' -- replace THE_ROLE with your role name
and granted_on = 'ROLE'
and privilege = 'USAGE'
and deleted_on is null;
```

You can also get the whole hierarchy with a recursive query, like this:

```
with cte as (
    select * 
    from snowflake.account_usage.grants_to_roles
    where grantee_name = 'THE_ROLE'  -- replace THE_ROLE with your role name
        and granted_on = 'ROLE'
        and privilege = 'USAGE'
        and deleted_on is null

    UNION ALL 

    select gtr.*
    from snowflake.account_usage.grants_to_roles gtr 
    join cte on gtr.grantee_name = cte.name
    where gtr.granted_on = 'ROLE'
    and gtr.privilege = 'USAGE'
    and gtr.deleted_on is null
)
select * from cte;
```

Querying the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE views is annoyingly snow, so I recommend creating a copy in your database and using it for playing and testing.